# Access serviceStack session inside AppHost to get userId for ioc injection for selfHosted app

Tags: c#, session, servicestack, inversion-of-control

I need to pass the userId to my dataAccess classes for auditing purposes and I am trying to inject it into my unitofwork class but i can figure out how to get the session. I can get the session inside the service classes by using  `SessionAs<>` but i cant figure out how to get the session in the Apphost so that i can pass the userId when registering the unitofwork in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session is dependent on the Incoming HTTP Request and as such is not available statically from the IOC - only at runtime within the Request Context of an incoming request.

As a result it can't be injected as a dependency, instead it should be passed into your dependency when its needed, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        Dependency.Exec(request, base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>());
    }
}
```

Whist not recommended, when hosted in ASP.NET you can access the current Request Context and get the session with:

```
var session = HttpContext.Current.ToRequest().GetSession();
```

> Note: `HttpContext.Current` will only be available in the context of a HTTP Request.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. that makes perfect sense. I was considering getting the session from the global request filter and passind it from there but your suggested way seems to be the better  option.